# Blackberry Object Handles and Persistent Object Handles?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Can someone please what are Object Handles and Persistent Object handles in Blackberry ? and how are they different ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each object that you use in your application will use one Object Handle (and if you had say a vector with 5 elements that would be 6 object handles since the vector itself is an object).  Each object in the PersistentStore uses a persistent object handle in addition to the regular object handle that it already uses.  You have a limited number of object handles and persistent object handles on the device and when you run out of handles your application will get an error.

Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

[Source](http://www.scribd.com/doc/4280957/BlackBerry-Application-Developer-Guide-Volume-2)

Comment: Are those Threads that hold those resources or keep them referenced so that the JVM doesnt Garbage Collect ? why exactly are those handles used for ?

Comment: No, handles definitely aren't threads.  I have no idea why RIM chose to implement it that way but as far as I can tell handles just limit the number of objects you can have.  Garbage collection works like it normally would.

Comment: Thank you. and are persistent object handles some kind of pointers to object persisted in the flash memory ?

Comment: I have no idea how they are implemented but they are just like regular object handles only there are less of them and they are for objects persisted in flash memory.

Comment: thnks Jonathan.. that was helpful

Comment: One small note - there is a link between the object handles in memory and the handles to persistent store. That is, the OS maintains the connection so when the object in memory changes, there is no need to set the content of the persistent object again, only have the store commit.